# The relation of weight loss speed and loose skin

Tags: dermatology, weight-loss, plastic-surgery, epidermis

For the past week I have been hunting for the answer to the following question:

Does the speed at which you lose weight have any relationship with loose skin? And the real question, why or why not?

I've reached out to every doctor friend I have, and requested they in turn reach out to dermatologists and plastic surgeons. I've sifted through a plethora of online resources, watched videos, used other question submission sites, and every time I either get a "Yes speed matters" or "No, speed doesn't matter", but **nobody** has even bothered to so much as guess why their stance is right while the opposite is wrong.

I have yet to find a single piece of non-anecdotal evidence for yes or no. If losing weight slowly allows ones epidermis to adjust to the weight loss than why would that function cease if the weight loss was quick?

If the epidermis can "shrink" then, to me, it stands to reason the only variable is time. But the reality that we have invasive, expensive surgical procedures to remove loose skin flies in the face of this.

If anyone can give me a "Yes, the speed of weight loss matters **because**..." or a "No, the speed of weight loss is irrelevant **because**..." I'd very much appreciate it. I'm starting to get the impression that every medical professional with an opinion on this is just regurgitating someone else's uneducated guess. Thanks!

Comment: Re: "it stands to reason the only variable is **x**", you should usually expect many, many variables. I don't have good data for you on this question, but any study is going to have to deal with a great deal of underlying variability, such that rate of weight loss would have to have a pretty a large effect size in order to be detected.